# How can I declare globals for jshint to ignore in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, jshint, sinon

I'm using sinon in my specs and including it in the Brocfile as describe in the [ember-cli docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#test-assets). This works and I can use sinon in my specs. But, jshint is complaining that sinon is not defined:

```
1 error: expected false to be truthy
    AssertionError: unit/views/edit-todo-test.js should pass jshint.
    unit/views/edit-todo-test.js: line 11, col 18, 'sinon' is not defined.
```

I can fix this by declaring sinon a global in the spec:

```
/* global sinon */
```

But, I'll have to add that to every spec (along with `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, etc....). I'd much rather just configure this once globally but when I add these globals to the `predef` array in .jshintrc, they aren't ignored and I still get the errors. For example:

.jshintrc:

```
{
  "predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "-Promise",
    "sinon"
  ],
<-- snip -->
```

still fails with the error `'sinon' is not defined.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're editing the wrong `.jshintrc` file.  The one located in the root directory is for the app.

There is an additional `.jshintrc` file for the tests.  Edit the one located at `/tests/.jshintrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it on a per file basis. For example, I have a library I only use in a service.

```
/* global ole*/
import Ember from 'ember';
import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    //code goes here
)}
```